# PHP - email validation fails

Tags: php, json, validation, email

From a multi-line text field I get several email addresses separated by new line. Field value is stored in database as a JSON string:

```
{"admin_emails":"email1@domain.com\r\nemail2@domain.com"}
```

Then I decode the emails using `json_decode` and `explode`:

```
$emailStr = json_decode($stringFromDb)->admin_emails; 
$emails = explode("\r\n", str_replace("\r", "\r\n", $emailStr) );
```

next, for each email in table, I check if it's valid and do some stuff:

```
foreach( $emails as $email )
{
    if( filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
        // do stuff with email
    }
}
```

But I have following problem: only the first email is recognized by the `filter_val` as valid email address. All subsequent emails are filtered out. What causes that these emails are not recognized as valid e-mail addresses?

Comment: You might want to call explode on $emailStr variable and not the string replaced version of that variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're replacing `"email1@domain.com\r\nemail2@domain.com"` with `"email1@domain.com\r\r\nemail2@domain.com"` - In other words `\r\r\n`. So all emails after the first start with a line break and thus are invalid.

You could simply do without the `str_replace()` all together

Comment: Yeah, my bad. I wanted to secure in case of different new line formats... I bit overdo it :D

Answer (score 0):

Maximus is correct:

```
<?php

$s ='{"admin_emails":"email1@domain.com\r\nemail2@domain.com"}';

//Then I decode the emails using json_decode and explode:

$emailStr = json_decode($s)->admin_emails;
$emails = explode("\r\n", $emailStr);

//next, for each email in table, I check if it's valid and do some stuff:

foreach( $emails as $email ) {
    if( filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ){
       echo $email." is valid\n\n";
        // do stuff with email
    }
}
```

This yields:

email1@domain.com is valid

email2@domain.com is valid